# Constraint Validation & knockout-validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, knockout.js

Is it possible to use knockout-validation for validation and displaying error messages using html constraints validation?

So basically I want to create validation using knockout validation and display errors using native tooltips:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/?redirect_from_locale=ja

Comment: Knockout validation already supports the [HTML5 Validation Attributes](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation#html5-validation-attributes), if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tomalak pointed out above Knockout validation does support html5 validation attributes. Unfortunately you cannot use the native tooltips to display errors.